# Unleash FEATURE TOGGLE for Spring Boot Microservices based on DATETIME Range?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, featuretoggle

I was looking at the documentation for UNLEASH feature toggle as I would like some add some feature-flag functionality in my Spring Boot application microservice (API).

I would like to "wrap" the logic in codebase with something like:

```
if(myCustomFeatureToggle.isActive()) {
    // do some stuff if toggle is ON
}
```

**However**, I believe the Unleash API has a UI web app you can access to turn these toggles ON or OFF (1 or 0). Someone has to manually type the URL into the browser and move a slider/UI element to turn ON or OFF the "feature". ***However***, **I would like to turn "ON" these toggles based on DATE range instead**. For example, I would like to set a datetime like `2021-12-30 00:00:00`, such that the toggle would become ACTIVE or ON on December 30, 2021 (without any manual intervention i.e. someone having to go to UI/web page and click some buttons). Having an "effective" and "end" date would also be awesome, i.e. end datetime for above example could be `2022-05-30 23:59:59`, such that the toggle automatically turns OFF on May 30, 2022 at 11:59 PM.

Is this possible? do any feature flags libraries have this functionality?

Comment: As discussed here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-feature-flags Togglz support release date

Comment: @HoseinIT if you make an answer instead of comment I will give you best answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with the help of [custom activation strategies](https://docs.getunleash.io/advanced/custom_activation_strategy). The example do provide an example of exactly time based activation.

There also exists a [issue request](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash/issues/765) to support this native in Unleash. It could be good if you can add your use case as a comment on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use Spring native *@RefreshScope* annotation. And when you want to change the feature flag value, just make a POST request to the actuator. You can make a simple bash/py script thats scheduled to make the request between the dates you want.

Here is a good guide:
[Introduction to @RefreshScope Annotation](https://medium.com/@erayaraz10/introduction-to-refreshscope-annotation-95d5dab4bcf1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).